# XSD - Presence of element depending on presence of other element(s)

Tags: xml, xsd

I have three possible elements inside a parent element:

```
<parent>
    <a>...</a>
    <b>...</b>
    <c>...</c>
</parent>
```

Inside `parent`, element `b` is only allowed when element `a` is present. Also, element `c` is only allowed when element `b` (and therefore also `a`) is present. In other words, the following configurations are allowed:

```
<parent>
    <a>...</a>
    <b>...</b>
    <c>...</c>
</parent>

<parent>
    <a>...</a>
    <b>...</b>
</parent>

<parent>
    <a>...</a>
</parent>
```

The following configurations are invalid:

```
<parent>
    <b>...</b>
</parent>

<parent>
    <c>...</c>
</parent>

<parent>
    <b>...</b>
    <c>...</c>
</parent>
```

Is this constraint expressable in XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the grammar is

```
( a, (b, (c)?)?)
```

which translates to

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="a"/>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element name="b"/>
    <xs:element name="c" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:sequence>
```